# Equivalent of next in purrr::map_df

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am looking for the equivalent of **next** in loops for a purrr::map_df call.

map_df plays nicely with dataframes that are NULL (as in the example below), so it works when I set `Result <- NULL` in my example below.

Could anyone suggest a general solution to my illustration below that would not require me setting `Result <- NULL`, but rather immediately go "next".

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1000)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), z = rep(LETTERS, 100))

Map_Func <- function(df) {

  Sum_Num <- suppressWarnings(sqrt(sum(df$y)))

  if( Sum_Num == "NaN" ) {

    Result <- NULL
    # I would like to have an equivalent to "next" here... 

    } else {

  Result <- df %>% filter(y == max(y)) %>% mutate(Result = x*y)

}

Result

}

Test <- split(df, df$z) %>% map_df(~Map_Func(.))
```

In the code above, what can I use instead of `Result <- NULL` in the ugly if statement (i.e. I want to simply check a condition and effectively do a "next").

Comment: what package is `group_split` from? it is not in standard dplyr

Comment: The `group_split` function is in `dplyr`, just only in the newest version. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_split.html But, you may want to modify the example, since most people are probably not on the latest version and thus not able to test this code. Not necessary, just FYI

Comment: @IceCreamToucan thanks - I adjusted code to not be dependent on using latest dplyr terminology.

Comment: In the function map is using you must return something. Instead of doing that else clause you could `return(NULL)` in the if clause which would be equivalent to next.

Comment: FYI, there's an `is.nan` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To exit a function you can use the `return(<output>)` command. This immediately exits the function with the output you define. The following gives the same output you were getting with your sample code.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1000)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), z = rep(LETTERS, 100))

Map_Func <- function(df) {

  Sum_Num <- suppressWarnings(sqrt(sum(df$y)))

  if( Sum_Num == "NaN" ) {

    return(NULL)

  } 

  Result <- df %>% filter(y == max(y)) %>% mutate(Result = x*y)
}

Test <- split(df, df$z) %>% map_df(~Map_Func(.))
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for thanks. Really cool way of adding stops in a map_df as it respects NULLs.

Answer (score 2):

Logic wise not a very different solution than OP but trying to keep it clean by using separate functions. `custom_check` function is to check the condition for each group. Using `map_if` we apply the function `Map_Func_true` only when `custom_check` returns `TRUE` or else apply `Map_Func_false` which returns `NULL` and finally bind the rows.

```
library(tidyverse)

Map_Func_true <- function(df) {
  df %>% filter(y == max(y)) %>% mutate(Result = x*y)
}

Map_Func_false <- function(df) { return(NULL) }

custom_check <- function(df) {
    !is.nan(suppressWarnings(sqrt(sum(df$y))))
}


df %>%
  group_split(z) %>%
  map_if(., custom_check, Map_Func_true, .else = Map_Func_false) %>%
  bind_rows()


# A tibble: 26 x 4
#       x     y z     Result
#   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>
# 1  1.24  2.00 A       2.47
# 2  1.24  2.00 A       2.47
# 3  1.24  2.00 C       2.47
# 4  1.24  2.00 C       2.47
# 5  1.24  2.00 E       2.47
# 6  1.24  2.00 E       2.47
# 7  1.24  2.00 G       2.47
# 8  1.24  2.00 G       2.47
# 9  1.24  2.00 I       2.47
#10  1.24  2.00 I       2.47
# … with 16 more rows
```

Comment: Your solution is too specific (the function is simply an illustration). Idea is more to get the map_df call to stop and carry on to next. @adam's solution provides a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: Your solution is interesting in general terms - never though of combining the map_if's in this way though...

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of looking at it using `purrr::safely`

```
Map_Func <- function(df) {

  Sum_Num <- suppressWarnings(sqrt(sum(df$y)))

  df %>% filter(y == max(y)) %>% mutate(Result = x*y)

}

Test <- split(df, df$z) %>% 
  map(safely(~Map_Func(.))) %>% 
  transpose() %>% 
  pluck("result") %>% # use 'error' here to get the error log
  bind_rows()
```

This way the function becomes cleaner and you also get a nice log of errors